.NET MAUIの8から9への移行
以下のようなコードを使っているアプリがあるのですが
.net MAUIを単純に8から9に移行すると
RequiredPermissions はoverrideするメソッドがありませんとなります
別の関数にする必要がありそうなのですが、マイクロソフトのサイトもRequiredPermissions をやはりこの様に使っています
フルビルドしたりしたのですが・・・
何か書き足す必要があったりするのでしょうか
/// <summary>
/// Near By Deviceの権限取得
/// </summary>
internal class PermissionNearByDevice : Permissions.BasePlatformPermission
{
#if ANDROID
        public override (string androidPermission, bool isRuntime)[] RequiredPermissions =>
             new List<(string androidPermission, bool isRuntime)>
             {
                // Near By Deviceは以下の権限を要求するようにすると設定画面を出せる
                (global::Android.Manifest.Permission.BluetoothScan,true),
                (global::Android.Manifest.Permission.BluetoothConnect,true),
                (global::Android.Manifest.Permission.BluetoothAdvertise,true)
             }.ToArray();
#endif
}


元ネタはおそらくこの記事 .NET MAUI 権限要求画面とSDKバージョンの取得 でしょうが、可能ならば作った人に質問してみてはどうでしょう？ それとも実はご本人なのだとしたら対象の.NET 9.0/MAUIのGitHubリポジトリとかMicrosoftのコミュニティに質問した方が早いと思われます。バグかもしれませんし。

公式ドキュメント にも記載があるのが不思議ですね。

お騒がせしました。Visual Studioのパッチがいくつか上がったので当ててみたら、解決しました。また別の問題が発生したのですが、こちらはクローズします。

その後Visual Studioのパッチがいくつか配信されたので適用したら解決しました。
ただの不具合だったようです。
